# Mesh To Volume - Applying Voronoi geonode to custom shape

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I've been looking at several tutorials showing how a voronoi texture geonode can be applied to a Volume Cube to create something like this:

[image: Tutorial from Ducky 3D]

What I'm looking to do is to apply the same Voronoi texture flow on a "Mesh To Volume." Now little did i know, the "Density" node between "Volume Cube" and "Mesh To Volume" have completely different behaviours. I've been looking at approaches like "Points to Volume" to find each individal voxel but no luck. Does anyone know if it is even possible to connect a "Voronoi Texture" geonode on to a custom shape to create the effect shown in the image attached?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299149/density-field-for-volumes-in-geometry-nodes  This is a way to work around the issue and may be what you are looking for.  I still think there may be other ways that I want to try, but it isn't as intuitive as I hoped