# Density field for volumes in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, volumetrics

The "points to volume" etc in Geometry Nodes has a density input.  This value is a single value, rather than a field.

Is it even possible to store and use a regional density ?  I've tried everything I can think of.
-Ideally I'd like to set a color and density value and retrieve that later in the shader editor for the principled volume.

It's driving me nuts that I can only get a "flat" density and color volume from geometry nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use *volume cube* for that.  For the mesh detection you can use *raycast* for example:

[image]

Comment: THAT is a fascinating solution.  Thank you!

Comment: Great solution but why must it be that difficult and counter intuitive?  Seems like the volume density input should be able to handle fields for meshes consistently not just for volume cubes.

Comment: It is a completely different domains of information. It is like Vector graphics and raster graphics, seems to be designed to make one thing, but converting from one type to other is quite tricky

Comment: Okay I used a capture attribute set to vector connecting position node output to capture attribute input and then passed that vector attribute from capture attribute output to attribute statistic and sent min and max outputs to volume cube min and max inputs to have cube size adjust to mesh size